# How remove noise from this image? [Python, cv2]

Tags: python, captcha, opencv

I am a newbie in both python and opencv and i can a remove noise from this and keep only text image:
[image]

I tried everything I found on the stackoverflow, nothing gave the right result.

Comment: that looks like a CAPTCHA. please present your research effort.

Comment: @RSNight RSNight, Please update informaion. This will help you avoid being voted any more(OMG, -2) and please also feedback to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

We cannot completely eliminate noise in the image. We can only minimize the noise. I used libs `cv2`, `numpy` and `matplotlid` Here I have made a small example with image color:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread("yourimage")
b,g,r = cv2.split(img)           # get b,g,r
rgb_img = cv2.merge([r,g,b])     # switch it to rgb

# Denoising
dst = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoisingColored(img,None,10,10,7,21)

b,g,r = cv2.split(dst)           # get b,g,r
rgb_dst = cv2.merge([r,g,b])     # switch it to rgb

plt.subplot(211),plt.imshow(rgb_img)
plt.subplot(212),plt.imshow(rgb_dst)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: Image output]

For more detail, you can refer to tutorial opencv.

[Image Denoising](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_photo/py_non_local_means/py_non_local_means.html)